# Fetch traffic to remote linux machine

Tags: linux, windows, networking, wireshark, network-traffic

We have recently migrated few services (DNS,DHCP etc ) from blucat proteus servers( Linux platform) to windows servers.Now the requirement is to find out any of our servers (intranet same subnet) is trying to reach these old server ips ( to ensure we are good to decom it).basically am looking for a script/tool which can run in one of my windows servers (if possible) and capture the traffic from my domain towards these old proteus linux machines.
wireshark can do this? if yes,how to configure it for this?
If not, is there any other tool or solution can help on this?

Comment: Hi, which network equipments do you have in the middle that can make your life easier? I suppose your "users" are pretty much all internal to your lan otherwise you wouldn't have asked for wireshark option. Any way you can assign the old IP address to a "dummy server or service" that can do the tracking (logging for you?)

Comment: routers are there and external requests to these servers can be captured as we have firewall setup there.but the requirement is to get the requests which are coming from internal ( same subnet windows/linux servers).we need to identify still any servers are trying to contact these old servers.(they were the DNS servers for all the servers in our infra)

Comment: "Any way you can assign the old IP address to a "dummy server or service" that can do the tracking". am afraid I didn't get what it mean .Please note these old servers are still active and we are looking for this information before they can go for decommisiion.

Comment: I see, so, why don't you trace the incoming traffic on those servers? it is the easiest way possible I guess

Comment: can you please suggest the steps how can we do that? am not sure how to use wireshark or any other tools in linux actually. (never worked on linux machines)

Comment: Sure I can help, can you tell me which distribution of Linux are you using? In addition, which SW solution are you using for DNS and DHCP?

Comment: they are blucat's own adonis linux release. DNS is now configured in our windows DC server ( integrated with AD)

Comment: I see, it should run iptables, just try to run sudo iptables -S and see if it is the case. If so, you can enable the logging on iptables for incoming connections

Comment: I was unable to run this command. ( connected to the server (SSH) using putty with an admin account).but it didn't allow me to type this command with spaces.after executed 'configure additional' and help command i have seen few options to check firewall status.("isenabled startup firewall" - it returned "No"). not sure where am I exactly..  :(